# Mocking a method with keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, mocking, python-unittest, keyword-argument

I am tying to unit test the function

```
def function(self, timeout):
    self.method1(self.method2(self.PARAM), timeout=timeout)
```

My current unit test is

```
patcher = patch("x.x.x.method2")
method2_mock = patcher.start()
self.addCleanup(patcher.stop)
...
@patch("x.x.x.method1")
def test_function(self, method1_mock):
    timeout = 1
    self.method2_mock.return_value = "val"
    self.page.function(timeout)
    self.method2_mock.assert_called_once_with(self.page.PARAM)
    method1_mock.assert_called_once_with("val", timeout=1)
```

When running the test, I get the following error in method1 in the actual function I am testing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
return func(*args, **keywargs)
...
File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1062, in __call__
return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1128, in _mock_call
ret_val = effect(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: local_side_effect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'
```

Why doesn't my mocked method1 accept the keyword argument and how can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the way I was patching the methods was critical to the issue. The first way, patching in the setup:

```
patcher = patch("x.x.x.method2")
method2_mock = patcher.start()
self.addCleanup(patcher.stop)
```

only allows me to use `assert` methods on the mocks.

However, patching for the individual test with

```
@patch("x.x.x.method1")
```

and passing the mock as an argument to the test, I am able to edit properties such as `return_value` and if mocked, its sub-properties. In this case the fix was simply to patch method2 with

```
@patch("x.x.x.method2")
```

and pass it to the test function

```
def test_function(self, method1_mock, method2_mock):
```